# How do I listen to multiple sockets at once using accept() in multiple threads?

Tags: c, multithreading, sockets

*Visual C/C++ in Visual Studio 2010*

I am working with a COM service made by someone else that creates multiple threads that run the same routine. In each thread, accept() is called on a socket. The sockets are identical except for the port number.

The problem is that when one thread calls accept(), the other thread is blocked. I have read some other posts on this website about threads in kernel space versus user space, but I don't really have control over that since I am implementing someone else's COM interface.

1. Is the blocking across threads happening because I am working in user space? How do I tell? I don't have access to the code that runs the 3rd party COM server application.
2. How do I tweak my current situation if I want to listen to multiple sockets at the same time?

**Other notes:**
*I tried using the same port but then bind() succeeds in one thread and fails in the other. From the MSDN documentation, I know that accept() is a blocking function by default, but I have the option of making it non-blocking. I haven't tried non-blocking yet.*

Here is the gist of my code. I trimmed error catching.

```
iRet = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

hints.ai_family     = AF_INET;
hints.ai_socktype   = SOCK_STREAM;
hints.ai_protocol   = IPPROTO_TCP;
hints.ai_flags      = AI_PASSIVE;

// Resolve the local address and port to be used by the server
iRet = getaddrinfo(NULL, iniListenPort, &hints, &result);

ListenSocket = socket(result->ai_family, result->ai_socktype, result->ai_protocol);

// Bind socket to local address
iRet = bind(ListenSocket, result->ai_addr, (int)result->ai_addrlen); // blocking

freeaddrinfo(result); // free memory allocated by getaddrinfo()

// Setup the TCP listening socket
if (listen(ListenSocket, SOMAXCONN) == SOCKET_ERROR)
```

This is called repeatedly:

```
// Accept a client socket
ClientSocket = accept(ListenSocket, NULL, NULL); // blocking

// We are receiving data
do {
    recvRet = recv(ClientSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0); // recv() ~ blocks and waits for data to arrive 
    } while (recvRet > 0)
```

Comment: What is your COM threading model? Are you an in-process or out-of-process COM server? Are you creating the threads yourself (and calling recv on them), or is "someone else" calling your COM methods on multiple threads?

Comment: In the standard unix way you just create the sockets, put them into listen state and add them to the read-fd_set. If any of them `select()`s to be readable, you call `accept()` on it, yielding a new connected socket. Threading may complicate things, but is not basically different.

Comment: The only way that one thread calling `accept()` can block another thread is if that second thread is synchronizing with the accepting thread and waiting for it do something. COM threading models may be a likely culprit, but it is hard to know for sure without seeing the actual code of the blocked thread or what it is actually blocking on.

Comment: Thanks all for the comments. I have addressed the issue by changing the ListenSocket to non-blocking and it seems to work so far. I just call accept() and recv() over and over rather than call-once-and-wait-for-finish.